# Is my analysis of this code correct, and why would it be written in this way?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, tuples

I inherited a python program (more like a large number of scripts) that I'm rewriting into an OOP program.  I'm still learning Python and ran into this line of code which I am uncertain about.

Unfortunately I don't know what this operation is called so my searches have not been very successful.

`bands = [int(b) for b in bands] if bands is not None else [10, 11]`

I think this code looks at the 'bands' variable and if it is not 'None', loops through the variable and casts each entry in the list to int.  If 'bands' is empty it sets 'bands' equal to a list containing 10 and 11.

Is my analysis of the code correct?

The code looks foreign to me though, kind of backwards.  Is there a specific reason someone would want to write code this way instead of a normal if statement?  Is it faster or does it have any other benefit?

Comment: yup. you got that right!

Comment: "Jessie, buy 10 eggs if they are available at the store, otherwise buy some bacon". Why does that code sound backwards to you? That's precisely how we speak. It's the normal `if` grammar that sounds strange... Anyway `if` requires 4 lines of code, which can be a waste when the condition is simple and you just do one assignment

Comment: 'list comprehension' is the term you are looking for.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I have found that "more concise" code does not necessarily translate into "more readable" or "more understandable" code. Being more concise is not always the best solution to a problem.  Thank you for your comment however.

Comment: @BenjaminKleynhans You'll also find that being extremely verbose is not good either. If assigning a bool requires 4 lines and 200 characters it takes you 1 minute to read. Once you know how `if` can be used as an expression it takes no time to learn to parse that code. As I said: you just read it as if it was english and it works. "bands is a list made of int(b) from bands if bands is not None else is [10, 11]" this is not hard to read. As I said, `if` expression is meant to be sued for **small** conditions and expressions and this case fits perfectly

Comment: Well, there are two Python features that you may be referring to: list comprehensions and conditional expressions. The fact that you used "kind of backwards" in your question suggests you're probably more confused by the conditional expression. I think the best explanation of that is in the ["What's New" section](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html) of the official documentation when the feature was introduced. The more formal [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) is watered down, overly clinical, and doesn't give nearly as much *insight* into the feature.

Comment: @JohnY I tend to think very logical and linear, and telling the compiler to cast something before you know if there is even something TO cast in the first place seems backwards.  Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is.

The left had side is a `list comprehension`. And you're correct. It uses the iterable `bands` to create a new list, where each element is the value returned by `int` for each element of `bands`.

But this will throw an exception if `bands` is `None`. So it only gets evaluated if `bands is not None`. If `bands` is `None` then it uses `[10, 11]` as a default value.

Learn about all the comprehensions (list, dictionary, set, and generator). They're super useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct.  I would have written this differently but I would not have used 4 lines to merely initialize/clean-up a variable when Python offers a variety of ways to be more concise yet just as legible.

Here are a few alternatives:

```
bands = [int(b) for b in bands] if bands else [10,11] # <-- I would have chosen this one
bands = [int(b) for b in bands or [10,11]]
bands = list(map(int,bands)) if bands else [10,11]
bands = list(map(int,bands or [10,11]))
bands = [*map(int,bands)] if bands or [10,11]
bands = [*map(int,bands or [10,11])]

# this is what I would NOT have done (too verbose and ignores Python's idioms):
if bands:
    bands = [int(b) for b in bands]
else:
    bands = [10,11]
```